# How to use RethinkDB's min/max functions with compound indices

Tags: python, rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

Suppose I have a RethinkDB table with `type` and `timestamp` fields. The `type` can be either `"good"` or `"bad"`. I would like to write a RethinkDB query which gets the `timestamp` of the most recent `"good"` document while making use of a [compound index](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/secondary-indexes/python/) with `type` and `timestamp`.

Here is an example script with one solution:

```
import faker
import rethinkdb as r
import dateutil.parser
import dateutil.tz

fake = faker.Faker()
fake.seed(0)            # Seed the Faker() for reproducible results

conn = r.connect('localhost', 28016)    # The RethinkDB server needs to have been launched with 'rethinkdb --port-offset 1' at the command line

# Create and clear a table
table_name = 'foo'  # Arbitrary table name
if table_name not in r.table_list().run(conn):
    r.table_create(table_name).run(conn)
r.table(table_name).delete().run(conn)      # Start on a clean slate

# Create fake data and insert it into the table
N = 5       # Half the number of fake documents
good_documents = [{'type':'good', 'timestamp': dateutil.parser.parse(fake.time()).replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())} for _ in range(N)]
bad_documents = [{'type':'bad', 'timestamp': dateutil.parser.parse(fake.time()).replace(tzinfo=dateutil.tz.tzutc())} for _ in range(N)]
documents = good_documents + bad_documents
r.table(table_name).insert(documents).run(conn)

# Create compound index with 'type' and 'timestamp' fields
if 'type_timestamp' not in r.table(table_name).index_list().run(conn):
    r.table(table_name).index_create("type_timestamp", [r.row["type"], r.row["timestamp"]]).run(conn)
    r.table(table_name).index_wait("type_timestamp").run(conn)

# Get the latest 'good' timestamp in Python
good_documents = [doc for doc in documents if doc['type'] == "good"]
latest_good_timestamp_Python = max(good_documents, key=lambda doc: doc['timestamp'])['timestamp']

# Get the latest 'good' timestamp in RethinkDB
cursor = r.table(table_name).between(["good", r.minval], ["good", r.maxval], index="type_timestamp").order_by(index=r.desc("type_timestamp")).limit(1).run(conn)
document = next(cursor)
latest_good_timestamp_RethinkDB = document['timestamp']

# Assert that the Python and RethinkDB 'queries' return the same thing
assert latest_good_timestamp_Python == latest_good_timestamp_RethinkDB
```

Prior to running this script, I launched RethinkDB at port 28016 using the command

```
rethinkdb --port-offset 1
```

I also use the [faker](https://github.com/joke2k/faker) package to generate fake data.

The query which I use, which combines `between`, `order_by`, and `limit`, does not seem particularly elegant or succinct, and I was wondering whether it is possible to use `max` for this purpose. However, it is not immediately clear to me from the documentation (https://www.rethinkdb.com/api/python/max/) how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you could replace this part of your query:

```
.order_by(index=r.desc("type_timestamp")).limit(1)
```

With:

```
.max(index="type_timestamp")
```

However that isn't currently possible. See https://github.com/rethinkdb/rethinkdb/issues/5141

Comment: Unfortunately this gives a `rethinkdb.errors.ReqlQueryLogicError: Expected type TABLE but found TABLE_SLICE:
SELECTION ON table(foo) in:
r.table('foo').between(['good', r.minval], ['good', r.maxval], index='type_timestamp').max(index='type_timestamp')`.

Comment: My suggestion indeed does not work. I've updated the answer